# Is it possible to override the Model.objects.all() method?

Tags: django

I want to return a filtered version of queryset when `MyModel.objects.all()` method is invoked. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).